# Removing "," from string

Tags: php

I would like to remove "," from string

```
$x="123,456,789";
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    if($x[$i]==",") $x[$i]="";
}
echo $x; //123456789 (Correct)

echo "<input type='text' value='$x'/>" //123?456?789 (Wrong)
```

It prints "?" in black box instead of ","

see this picture http://postimg.org/image/rky151535/

Comment: use `str_replace(',', '', $x);`

Comment: He just built a Rube Goldberg machine. Nice!

Comment: Save some google searches, guys: http://mashable.com/2013/08/21/rube-goldberg-machines/

Comment: Your loop [works fine for me](http://3v4l.org/pqQor), but you should still use str_replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ditch the for loop:

```
$x = str_replace (',','',$x);
```

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are serious using a for loop here.

Just use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace all occurrences of the search with a replace.

```
$x = str_replace (',', '', $x);
```

Anyway, if you are going to show only the numbers and want to strip out everything else, use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$x = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $x);
```

Above line replaces everything except 0-9 with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x="123,456,789"; 
$pattern = '/,/'; 
$replace = ''; 
$x= preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $x);
echo $x;
```

**or**

```
     $x = str_replace (',','',$x);
     echo $x;
```

Comment: str_replace is faster than the preg_replace. http://codepad.org/B5ZpPWLD

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
$x = str_replace(',', '', $x); 
echo $x;
```